# Generating RESTful API documentation from a WCF Service

Tags: wcf, rest

I've recently started on a project to build out a RESTful API in WCF, and I'm going to need to expose documentation along with the API itself. I was hoping to leverage the XML code comments in my docs for this documentation.

But what I want to output is just the contracts that are exposed by the service: the endpoints and the JSON/XML object structures. Since I'm trying to create external documentation, I'm interested in any of the internals of my library, or how it ties into the .Net Framework (or even that it is .Net, for that matter).

What are my options for tools, to create these docs? I've heard that Sandcastle or Doxygen are good tools for generating docs from XML code comments, but can I filter away the classes and methods that I don't want to expose?

Comment: This is not REST, please remove the [restful] tag. If your endpoint URIs are in your API, it is just RPC.

Comment: @aehlke What part of the above suggests to you that this is not WCF REST implementation?

Comment: Maybe he means the trend that good rest APIs represent the object graph within the layout and structure of their docs, like http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can filter unwanted APIMembers with Sandcastle. [This blogentry](http://blogs.msdn.com/sandcastle/archive/2008/06/18/filtering-apis-using-sandcastle.aspx) describes how. If you are new to Sandcastle, you might want to try out [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/) as well, which is basically a [Sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/) Frontend.

Comment: +1 - SHFB is a lifesaver, and cuts down the time to configure your output to the point that it is painless.  I have also worked with integrating it with my Team Build process, so we always have up to date documentation.

Answer (score 11):

I understand this question was asked pre-.NET 4.0, but as of .NET 4.0, you can create a 'help page' as as described in [WCF Web HTTP Service Help Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230442.aspx).

#### WCF 4.0 Example

```
[System.ComponentModel.Description("Triggers Method Name Behavior.")]
public void MethodName() {}
```

Comment: +1 This is exactly what I was looking for for .NET 4! Kudos @RickGlos

Answer (score 0):

You could config doxygen to generate document from files speficied.  Why not have a look a the documents of doxygen?